# Gradle sync failed: Can’t get application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp"

Tags: android, growl

After i upgrade to Android 2.1.3 i got this error:

```
"1:05:48 PM Gradle sync failed: Can’t get application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp".
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
1:06:42 PM Gradle sync started
1:06:43 PM Gradle sync failed: Can’t get application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp".
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Have no clue what should i do, any help? thanks!

Comment: `Show Log` says what? Anything you would like to share in this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade my gradle by choose **"Pereference" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> Gradle - > "Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)"** then it works.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not certain if this counts as a canonical "answer", when I installed macOS Sierra, I did get a notification stating that Growl would no longer run.  This appears to be supported by Growl's own website as it cannot even be built from source on a modern Xcode or OS X see: http://growl.info/documentation/developer/growl-source-install.php

Unless we can find a way to strip the reliance on Growl out of the Android Studio itself, I don't know that it will be functional on macOS Sierra.  It does appear to be baked into several of the jars, though I'm sure someone more resourceful than I will come up with a nifty workaround.

**EDIT** I was able to build my project by opening the project's build.gradle (Project: project_name_here), and commenting out:

```
//apply plugin: 'announce'
//apply plugin: 'build-announcements'
```

From the bottom of the file.  This did allow gradle to continue and build my project, which is running just fine.

Comment: Thank you Chris, i think you shot good points! Some times just waste time on questions like this, so just downgrade something to make work done.